# last regex match in Python

Tags: python, regex

I would like to capture `NP_054520.1` (last brackets). Unfortunately, the below code catch the first one.

```
>>> import re
>>> a="cytochrome b6/f complex subunit V %28plastid%29  %28NP_054520.1%29"
>>> re.search(r'%28(.*?)%29', a).group(1)
'plastid'
```

What did I miss?

Thank you in advance,

Comment: (.*?)  that ? symbol will give you first match always

Comment: Did any of the provided answers help you solve the problem?

Answer (score 0):

```
>>> import re
>>> a="cytochrome b6/f complex subunit V %28plastid%29  %28NP_054520.1%29"
>>> re.search(r'.*%28(.*)%29', a).group(1)
```

'NP_054520.1'

Answer (score 0):

Would you please try the following:

```
import re
a = "cytochrome b6/f complex subunit V %28plastid%29  %28NP_054520.1%29"
m = re.findall(r'%28(.*?)%29', a)
print(m[-1])     # last element of the list "m"
```

which outputs:

```
NP_054520.1
```

Answer (score 0):

As there are no spaces between `%28` and `%29`, you could also capture one or more non whitespace characters using `\S+` and assert the end of the string `\Z`

```
%28(\S+)%29\Z
```

See a [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/b2nImq/1) and a [Python demo](https://ideone.com/3kO1gY)

```
import re
a="cytochrome b6/f complex subunit V %28plastid%29  %28NP_054520.1%29"
print(re.search(r'%28(\S+)%29\Z', a).group(1))
```

Output

```
NP_054520.1
```